# Extracting objects from List<X> based on some other list property collection

Tags: java, collections, guava

I've a class -

```
public class Data implements Identifiable{
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

now I've two collections-

```
List<Data> data1 = // few hundred Objects

Set<Integer> dataIds = // few object ids
```

I would like to extract the `List<Data>` from `data1` which has ids in `dataIds`

How should be my approach? I'va guava in my classpath so can go with guava's Functional approach if comparable in performance/efficiency .

Comment: If dataId's corresponds to List<Data> objects' ID's, then why one is an Integer when the other is a Long ?

Also, what collection type are used? e.g. : Is data1 an ArrayList<Data>, or a LinkedList ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless all you want to do is iterate through the result once or you need a reusable live filtered view, you probably want a non-view list containing the matches. Creating a `List` or `Set` to store the result and then iterating through the data list and adding matches is a perfectly good approach and easy to understand!

```
List<Data> result = Lists.newArrayList();
for (Data data : data1) {
  if (dataIds.contains(data.getId()))
    result.add(data);
}
```

I see your `Data` class implements an `Identifiable` interface. Given that, you  could create a `Function<Identifiable, Integer>` that gets the ID... `Identifiables.getIdFunction()` or something. This is nice because it'd likely be useful in various other places (I talk about that approach in a blog post [here](http://blog.cgdecker.com/2010/06/property-interfaces-and-guava.html)). With that in place, doing this with Guava would be fairly simple as well:

```
Predicate<Identifiable> predicate = Predicates.compose(
    Predicates.in(dataIds), Identifiables.getIdFunction());
List<Data> filtered = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(data1, predicate));
```

This is basically functionally equivalent to the first example, but seems like it'd be harder to understand. Since there isn't any clear benefit to doing this (unlike in a situation where you want to just use the live view), my recommendation would be to just go with the first.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
Collections2.filter(
    data1,
    new Predicate<Data>() {
       public boolean apply(Data d) {
         return dataIds.contains(d.getId());
       }
    }
)
```

p.s. [remember not to overcomplicate](http://konigsberg.blogspot.com/2009/10/story-time-with-google-collections.html) things, unless truly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With [LambdaJ](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures) you could write:

```
List<Data> result = extract(data1, on(Data.class).getId());
```